# SSRS IIF expression giving only partial output

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, iif

I have a simple IIF statement to say if the actual date is blank, show me TBC. Otherwise, show me what the actual date is. I can successfully get the TBC. But I cannot get the actual date to show where I know there is a date. Any help is appreciated.

```
=IIF(Fields!VPSR_Actual_Date.Value = "", "TBC", Fields!VPSR_Actual_Date.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do a check if the column is null or zero string and then format the date.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(CStr(Fields!VPSR_Actual_Date.Value)) OR CStr(Fields!VPSR_Actual_Date.Value) ="", "TBC", Format(Fields!VPSR_Actual_Date.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```